# How to bend rigged mesh in wanted direction

Tags: rigging

This is horse mesh I want to rig for exporting to game. I'm very new to rigging so I want horse to bend legs more natural. This is surely not how animal would bend leg if it lifts it up like on my picture, it looks like it is made of rubber. I was messing with IK constraints and weight painting but I am not actually sure what that does.
What I ask is how can I affect it to bend like I want(direction) - is it by weight painting, by IK restraints. Maybe some good tutorial about rigging could come handy!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you don't have a pole target. Check out this video for more information:[Inverse Kinematics video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-2v_CKmVE8)

Comment: Go to 7:34 to find the information you're looking for

Comment: Thanks, rigging is bit complicated ,but this tutorial is so good. I will manage to solve problem!